# Adjusting the scale of the ScrollViewer scroolbar

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have a stackpanel being built dynamically, filling with a certain amount of user controls. Because the space is limited, I use Scrollviewer on the stack panel, with a styled Scrollbar.

What happens next is fairly annoying, As I scroll all the way there is always a little extra buffer between the last control and the bottom of the scrollviewer/stackpanel. I think the reason this happens is that the scrollviewing area is set to a specific height(which I need to keep). The size of the user controls is determined by that height divided by number of user controls (for example 10). What happens is when I scroll all the way down and there are less user controls to show (lets say 8) it fills out the rest of the predetermined height with background color.

Please, advise on what can I do to change the behavior of scroll bar, or scrollviewer control, so the extra part disappears?

Code for the scrollviewer

```
        <Border Name="ScrollViewerBorder" BorderThickness="1,0,1,0" BorderBrush="{StaticResource BorderLight}" Height="{Binding MidHeight}" >
            <ScrollViewer Name="midScroll1" Style="{StaticResource ScrollViewer04}" d:DesignHeight="612" Width="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" CanContentScroll="False" Background="{StaticResource LtBlue}" >

                <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="left" Name="Midmenu" Background="{StaticResource LtBlue}" Width="300" CanVerticallyScroll="True">
            </StackPanel>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Border>
```

part of the scroll bar style xaml

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="VerticalScrollBar04" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}" >
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="56" />
            <RowDefinition Height="0.00001*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="56" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <!--Border around buttons and thumb-->
        <Border Grid.RowSpan="3" CornerRadius="0" Background="{StaticResource White}" BorderBrush="{StaticResource ButtonLine}" BorderThickness="1" />

        <RepeatButton Grid.Row="0" Height="56" Command="ScrollBar.LineUpCommand" Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarTopButton04}" />

        <Track Name="PART_Track" Grid.Row="1" IsDirectionReversed="true" ViewportSize="NaN" >
            <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                <RepeatButton Command="ScrollBar.PageUpCommand" Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarPageButton04}" />
            </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
            <Track.Thumb>
                <Thumb Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarThumb04}" Margin="0,10,0,10" />
            </Track.Thumb>
            <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                <RepeatButton Command="ScrollBar.PageDownCommand" Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarPageButton04}" />
            </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
        </Track>

        <RepeatButton Grid.Row="2" Height="56" Command="ScrollBar.LineDownCommand" Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarBottomButton04}" />

    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: `I have a stackpanel being built dynamically` - the very beginning of your question suggest you're using the wrong approach. You don't "build" anything "dynamically" in WPF. Use an `ItemsControl` instead.

Comment: put it inside a dockpanel instead of a stackpanel and get rid of the fixed height

Comment: Not familiar with ItemsControl. Do I just bind the itemsource of it to the observable collection of my usercontrols?

Comment: I've tried ItemsControl and assign itemsource on the backend after i create my collection. The menues generate ok, but the scrollbar is glued to the bottom and not moving. I guess I am missing something.

Comment: HighCore, thank you for the suggestion, I think the performanec improved a bit using **itemscontrol**, and although I had to fight through the **scrollviewer** style issue, in the end Human 1: WPF 0. No additional **StackPanels** or **Grids** were needed. Although, at some point of time I placed **scrollvewer** inside of the items control, as many tutorials suggest, I encountered the same problem with the height.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".